# Web Api for OData V4 doesn't Work With HasKey

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2, odata-v4

I'm using web api 2.2 for odata v4, and below is the models:

```
[Table("User")]
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        UserRoles = new HashSet<UserRole>();
    }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
}

[Table("UserRole")]
public partial class UserRole
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

and below is the WebApiConfig.cs code:

```
        ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<User>("Users");
        builder.EntitySet<UserRole>("UserRoles");            
        config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", builder.GetEdmModel());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

Till now, every thing works well.
But, if I remove the [Key] form the UserRole definition. and use the code :

```
builder.EntitySet<UserRole>("UserRoles").EntityType.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleName });
```

The when I query on User, I always get the error that tells UserRoles has no key definition.

I have upload the source porject files @ https://cloud.seafile.com/f/bdff340ec3/
Please check the webapiconfig.cs User.cs UserRole.cs and web.config (for database connection string).
When you access /odata/Users?$expand=UserRoles you will get the error

Comment: It is strange that I can get two keys defined after I call HasKey. Can you share more info to repro the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just change

```
builder.EntitySet<UserRole>("UserRoles").EntityType.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleName });
```

To

```
EntityTypeConfiguration<UserRole> userRoleType=builder.EntitySet<UserRole>("UserRoles").EntityType;
userRoleType.HasKey(p=>p.UserId);
userRoleType.HasKey(p=>p.RoleName);
```

Comment: using this way doesn't work. when I try to access http://localhost:60740/odata/Users?$expand=UserRoles I got the error  "message":"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\nWebApplication1.Models.OData.UserRole: : EntityType 'UserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.\r\nUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserRoles' is based on type 'UserRole' that has no keys defined.\r\n","type":"System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Mode......

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Here is what I am doing right now, not finished so I do not know if there will be other issues.

In my model I changed UserId to Id so OData convention will use it as the key and then in my dbcontext map file I used:

```
public class DbLdapMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<DbLdap>
{
    public DbLdapMap()
    {
        ToTable("LDAP");

        //Primary Key
        HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");

    }
}
```

I really want to keep all the database definitions in the Fluent API.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your project, and the odata metadata "/odata/$metadata" seems fine to me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="4.0" xmlns:edmx="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edmx">
  <edmx:DataServices>
    <Schema Namespace="WebApplication1.Models.OData" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityType Name="User">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="Id" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="Id" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="UserRoles" Type="Collection(WebApplication1.Models.OData.UserRole)" />
      </EntityType>
      <EntityType Name="UserRole">
        <Key>
          <PropertyRef Name="UserId" />
          <PropertyRef Name="RoleName" />
        </Key>
        <Property Name="UserId" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <Property Name="RoleName" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
        <NavigationProperty Name="User" Type="WebApplication1.Models.OData.User" />
      </EntityType>
    </Schema>
    <Schema Namespace="Default" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/ns/edm">
      <EntityContainer Name="Container">
        <EntitySet Name="Users" EntityType="WebApplication1.Models.OData.User">
          <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="UserRoles" Target="UserRoles" />
        </EntitySet>
        <EntitySet Name="UserRoles" EntityType="WebApplication1.Models.OData.UserRole">
          <NavigationPropertyBinding Path="User" Target="Users" />
        </EntitySet>
      </EntityContainer>
    </Schema>
  </edmx:DataServices>
</edmx:Edmx>
```

***The problem is that UserRole has no keys defined in the DB model rather than the OData EDM model.***

If you remove the Key attribute on UserId and RoleName, the DBModelBuilder doesn't know what the keys are.

So you need to add the following code to ***Database.OnModelCreating*** without [Key]:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>()
                .HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleName });
```

What is more, you need to ***add EnableQuery attribute on the action if you want to support to apply $expand on the result***:

```
        [EnableQuery]
        public IQueryable<User> GetUsers()
        {
            var db = new Database();
            return db.Users;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But please check the source code WebApiConfig.cs, in that file, I do have the code as builder.EntitySet<UserRole>("UserRoles").EntityType.HasKey(r => new { r.UserId, r.RoleName }); But access /odata/Users?$expand=UserRoles  still throw the exeption.

Comment: Check my answer, it should be in "Database.OnModelCreating"(DB model), not WebApiConfig.cs(OData EDM model)